# Using Haxedoc to generate documentation for my project

Tags: documentation, haxe

I wrote my html5 game api with haxe and now I want to auto-generate the documentation from the comments in the code. However, I have no idea how to even get started on this. I want to try to use haxedoc but the only documentation I have is on this website and it's not very helpful at all: http://haxe.org/doc/haxedoc

When I run this command: haxe -xml output.xml build.hxml

it says build.hxml does not exist.

How do I get haxedoc to go through my project and generate the documentation?
Specific steps are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .hxml to use for the documentation. How to create a .hxml is documented here http://haxe.org/doc/compiler#example

Comment: Do you have to make an hxml file? It's extremely tedious for the number of files I have.

Comment: The hxml file only contains instructions how to build the project, that is needed for the documentation. So yes I think it's needed.

Comment: Well the thing is I just want to document the framework and not the game so the game itself has a build file but not the framework. I never build the framework alone so I find this kind of strange. The framework doesn't run by itself at all so I still need to make this file.

Comment: Well I think this does make sense, you want docs of the framework, then you need to build the framework completely. Otherwise you get project related classes in it too. What kind of target is it? I can create a simple hxml for you, it is maybe 4 lines of instructions.